# Conditional Angular JS sub-form validation

Tags: angularjs

I can use ng-required to evaluate whether a field is required. Can I specify whether an entire sub-form is required?

For example, I have three radio buttons and each opens up a different sub form. But only the selected sub-form is required. The other two can be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to show\submit one form, use `ng-switch` or [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf) to stop emitting of DOM for other form.

`ng-if` is part of Angular version 1.1.5